# getApplicationContext with xml layout from resources

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I'm stuck on a piece of code.
I have a PHP page that is getting my values from the database that's all okay.
Then in my Activity I'm returning it to show in a textview, the problem is that.
I got in my xml a background but it isn't showing,

Also I see in my textview 
http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/leesverslag.php{"introtext":""my variable values from the database"}

this is my activity

```
public class Leesverslag extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView txt;

public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/leesverslag.php"; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leesverslag);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.
    ScrollView rootLayout = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    //txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.verslag);
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
    rootLayout.addView(txt);  
    setContentView(rootLayout);
    // Set the text and call the connect function.  
    txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
    //call the method to run the data retrieval and convert html tag to (plain) text
    txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getServerData(KEY_121))); 
}

private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
   String titelhoofd = getIntent().getStringExtra("titelverslag");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("titel",titelhoofd));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getString("introtext")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}    

}
```

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verslag"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I would like to see just the text and my background, but I can't seem to get it fixed.

Can somebody help me with this?

Kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting an initial content view with `setContentView(R.layout.leesverslag);` after which you continue to create a new view that you use to overwrite the first one with.

Try to replace this:

```
ScrollView rootLayout = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
//txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.verslag);
txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
rootLayout.addView(txt);  
setContentView(rootLayout);
// Set the text and call the connect function.  
txt.setText("Connecting...");
```

with this:

```
txt = (TextView)findByViewId(R.id.*yourtextviewid*)
txt.setText("Connecting...");
```

This assigns the TextView that is on your initial content view to `txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the help now I got my own XML layout instead of default.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add more than one view to scroll view directly 
just take a reference to your LinaerLayout like the way in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/Linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

then in your on create method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.leesverslag);
LinearLayout mLinearlayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
    mLinearlayout.addView(txt);

    Runnable postRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getServerData(KEY_121))); 

        }
    };
    txt.post(postRunnable,500);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help now I got my own XML layout instead of default.

Comment: you must answer it so that other looking for the problem must get the solution or else use the above one an approve it so that other user can use it .........